# Expand empty space in table cell

Tags: css

I want to make HTML table row clickable using html link.
See here http://s31.postimg.org/mdsm5ad7f/Untitled.png

```
tr.clickable td a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: green;
}
```

As you can see on the picture in empty table rows the clickable area is not expanded to fill the cell. How I can fix this? I would like to expand the green area in table cell.

Comment: can you share the HTML and CSS code of your table?

Comment: Here you are http://pastebin.com/07W8p5jf

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

CSS

```
.td_text {
  background: #CCC;
}
.td_link {
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.td_link a {
  background: green;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td_link"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="td_text">text<br>text<br>text<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below css and it will be help you to solve the issue.

```
.td_link a {
  background: green;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```